# MySQL server fails to install even with Visual C++ Redistributable install

Tags: mysql

I don't know why but when I try to install MySQL server version 5.7.20 it fails to install even if I have the Microsoft Visual C++ 2013  Redistributable versions for 32-bit and 64-bit installed.

The end of the log just says this:

```
Position: -459
Position: -460
Position: -461
Position: -462
Position: -463
Position: -464
Position: -465
Position: -466
Position: -467
Position: -468
Position: -469
Position: -470
Position: -471
Position: -472
Position: -473
Position: -474
Position: -475
Position: -476
Position: -477
1: MySQL Server 5.7 2: {81B27388-3733-4B65-8D84-AD9C9113B498} 3: 3 
MySQL server failed to install
```

Comment: Did you reboot after installing the Visual C++ libraries?

Comment: yes i did like 3 times and i even try repairing them and rebooting and nothing